# Plot bar charts on a map in plotly

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I want to plot a bar chart on a map created with plotly, similar to the QGIS plot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqjjw.png). Ideally, the bar chart would be stacked and grouped instead of just grouped. So far, I only found examples for pie charts on plotly maps, for instance [here](https://plotly.com/javascript/bubble-maps/).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- with **plotly** **mapbox** you can add layers
- with **plotly** you can generate images from figures
- using above two facts you can add URI encoded images to a **mapbox** figure
- you have not provided any sample geometry or data.  Have used a subset **geopandas** sample geometry plus generated random data for each country (separate graph)
- the real key to this solution is [layer-coordinates](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/mapbox/#layout-mapbox-layers-items-layer-coordinates)

  - get centroid of a country
  - add a buffer around this and get envelope (bounding rectangle)
  - arrange co-ordinates of envelope to meet requirements stated in link

```
import geopandas as gpd
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import base64, io

# create an encocded image of graph...
# change to generate graph you want
def b64image(vals=np.random.randint(1, 25, 5)):
    fig = px.bar(
        pd.DataFrame({"y": vals}).pipe(
            lambda d: d.assign(category=d.index.astype(str))
        ),
        y="y",
        color="category",
    ).update_layout(
        showlegend=False,
        xaxis_visible=False,
        yaxis_visible=False,
        bargap=0,
        margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
        autosize=False,
        height=100,
        width=100,
        paper_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
        plot_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    )

    b = io.BytesIO(fig.to_image(format="png"))
    b64 = base64.b64encode(b.getvalue())
    return "data:image/png;base64," + b64.decode("utf-8"), fig

# get some geometry
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
# let's just work with a bounded version of europe
eur = world.loc[
    lambda d: d["continent"].eq("Europe")
    & ~d["iso_a3"].isin(["RUS", "NOR", "FRA", "ISL"])
]


px.choropleth_mapbox(
    eur,
    geojson=eur.__geo_interface__,
    locations="iso_a3",
    featureidkey="properties.iso_a3",
    color_discrete_sequence=["lightgrey"],
).update_layout(
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
    showlegend=False,
    mapbox_style="carto-positron",
    mapbox_center={
        "lon": eur.unary_union.centroid.x,
        "lat": eur.unary_union.centroid.y,
    },
    mapbox_zoom=3,
    # add a plotly graph per country...
    mapbox_layers=[
        {
            "sourcetype": "image",
            # no data provided, use random values for each country
            "source": b64image(vals=np.random.randint(1, 25, 5))[0],
            # https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/mapbox/#layout-mapbox-layers-items-layer-coordinates
            # a few hops to get 4 cordinate pairs to meet mapbox requirement
            "coordinates": [
                list(p) for p in r.geometry.centroid.buffer(1.1).envelope.exterior.coords
            ][0:-1][::-1],
        }
        for i, r in eur.iterrows()
    ],
)
```

#### output

[image]

Comment: I finally managed to implement this but had to realize that the resulting aspect ratio is not really suited for my purposes. So, ideally I would like to change the projection but mapbox figures do not seem to support this. On the other hand, geo maps do not seem to support layers.

Comment: @lego correct - mapbox uses epsg:4286 and geo plots do not have layers

Comment: So, in conclusion, what I want to do is not possible with plotly?

Comment: I'm sure it is possible in plotly by generating images and putting together.   I put quite a lot of work into this then you decided to state you don't want to use standard projections.  Hence more work is probably wasted as probably you'll reject after revealing more about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Your solution was still very helpful and did not intend to complain, just to make sure I got it right. I will try some solution with layering images and post the solution here if I succeed.